# Add c++ compiler flags using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I am quite new to the whole CMake logic and syntax. For the code I am working on, I need to use the `cap_set_proc` function to work with a process capabilities flags ([man link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cap_set_proc.3.html)). So I decided to start with a really stupid piece of code that you see here:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sys/capability.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    cap_t test = cap_get_proc();
    string whatsTest(cap_to_text(test,nullptr));
    cout<<whatsTest<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

(For the moment, I do not care if the code I wrote makes any sense...)
Now, if I simply use `c++` (as shown below) everything compiles fine and the executable runs without any issue:

```
c++ test_main.cpp -o test_cap -lcap
```

The problem is that the project I am working one is pretty huge and relies on CMake pretty heavily. So I wanted to compile the same code but using CMake... How do I write a CMakeLists.txt file that allows me to obtain the same result as the compiler instruction shown in the previous lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like the following should be all you need:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(TestCapProject)

# Add your executable target.
add_executable(test_cap test_main.cpp)

# Link the libcap library to your executable.
target_link_libraries(test_cap PRIVATE cap)
```

If you're adding this to an existing CMake project, you may only need the last two or three lines, depending on your project hierarchy.

I suggest reading through the CMake [guide](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html) to get your bearings on some basic CMake commands.

The documentation for the two primary commands you need is here:

- [`add_executable()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html)
- [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#command:target_link_libraries)

Comment: It worked just fine. Thanks for the help and also for the theory tips.